# Market for capital goods of housing: Name of the model

Tags: microeconomics, reference-request, housing, capital

I am searching for a model of the market for capital goods applied on purchase prices, rents, and supply of new housing.

The model, operating in continuous time, considers prices as a function of future discounted rents, derives the demand for houses as a function of said rents.

Importantly, the model was interesting by simultaneously analyzing two situations: 1) **The steady relations** between stable level of capital (i.e., houses) and demand for houses, denoting steady state. 2) **The relation between prices of houses and current capital**, depicted in a **phase diagram**, utilizing saddle path between stable stock (denoted by supply of capital) and stable prices (depending on the demand for capital).

**Do you know how is this model called?**